# crear un progress bar con imagen de fondo

Tags: css, progressbar, background

estoy creando un indicador de progreso que vaya llenando una botella de acuerdo al porcentaje de la propiedad height de la clase progress, el objetivo es ver la botella llena cuando el porcentaje este al 100%., el siguiente es el código html.

cuando la botella se va llenando tengo el problema de que no toma solo la figura de la botella sino que el progresso es rectangular.

el div de la clase .progress alrededor al cambiar el height 60% no se ve dentro de la imagen de la botella.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-10">
                <div class="loader-container" >
                    <div id="botella">
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress pt-5" style="height:0%"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.loader-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto 0.6em;
    background-color: #f5f2f6;
}   
    #botella{
        width:400px;
        height:400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        text-indent: -99999em;
        text-align: left;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 101%;        
    }

 #botella2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

 #botella::after {
  content: "";
  background: url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/b3a503_7f83c233460d48e1be6305dc7cdbe902.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 400px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}


 .progress {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14px;
    left: 150px;
    width: 105px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: height 1s ease-out;
    border-radius: 0 0 24px 24px;
}
```

he creado un pen para vert el funcionamiento
https://codepen.io/manuelf0710/pen/oNxGMVM

Comment: Pinta una botella con interior transparente. Pones la barra de progreso en una capa bajo la botella y la haces funcionar normalmente. Como sólo el interior de la botella es transparente el efecto visual será de llenado.

Comment: lo que queria era buscar la forma en que una imagen como la del ejemplo se viera con efecto de llenado actualmente tiene el problema cuando el div .progress tiene un height superior alrededor del 60% y superior. el objetivo es lograr una imagen que no pierda muchos detalles al tener el interior en transparente realmente solo se veria la forma de la botella y no la parte de logos o letras.